# Capitalize a single letter instead of the entire sentence

Tags: c++, toupper

How do I uppercase for example letter "i"? I tried transform, convert.  Now, I think using a for loop may be the best option, but cannot seem to figure it out!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
string s = "this is a test, this is also a test, this is yet another test";
int strLen = 0;
strLen = s.length();
for() //this is where I can't seem to figure it out
cout << s << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Here's the answer: `s[0] = std::toupper(s[0]);`.  Replace `0` with the position of the letter you want to capitalize.

Comment: Here you go: `for(auto& c : s) { c = c == 'i' ? (char)std::toupper(c) : c; }`

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Thank you.  You solution works, but involves multiple entries.  I appreciate it.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ AWESOME! Thank you very much.

Comment: It's not generally safe to call `std::toupper` on a `char` value from a `std::string` - you should use `std::toupper(static_cast<uint8_t>(c))`.  See [cppreference docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper) - the argument is an `int` and must be representable as an `unsigned char`.  Simply `char` - the element type in `std::string`, may be signed or unsigned depending on your implementation.  (The reason for this is so implementations may simply index into an array of 256 `char`s - where the lowercase ones are replaced with uppercase ones, using the input as an index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an `std::` way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  string s = "this is a test, this is also a test, this is yet another test";
  char ch = std::toupper('i');
  std::replace(s.begin(), s.end(), 'i', ch);
  cout << s << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
// Assume that all dependencies have been included
void replaceAllLetters (string& s, char toReplace) {
    char new = std::toupper(toReplace);
    std::replace(s.begin, s.end, toReplace, new);
}
void replaceOneLetter (string& s, int index) {
  if (index < s.size()) s[index] = std::toupper(s[index]);
}
```